# Unable to show map fragments in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

its more of a theoretical(configuration issue)
i have been working on this android application in which i have included google maps and it was working fine as planned, the problem i encountered was that i tried and transferred the project from my laptop to my friend's laptop the project stops working i.e. the application crashes as soon as it proceeds to the activity where the map fragment is present, we have made sure that we have google play services installed and imported the downloaded services into the workspace as required as well as i have made sure that the google play services are also included with in the project, i have also tried to change the API key but nothing works, the app crashes as soon as the app proceeds to the activity featuring maps
here is the error(logcat)
[image]

[image]

I have been stuck with this issue for a few days now, any help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me when mistakenly changing my map fragment from SupportMapFragment to MapFragment.

So check that your map is the correct type, whichever you are using, and that the imports are of type SupportMapFragment. Might very well have auto imported the wrong type if the support library was included after moving the project.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when passing `Google Maps API V2` project from one computer to other... The main problem that usually happens is that you have to generate a new API key using the `Google's API Console`.

But and that a huge but... usually people do that after they noticed they have a problem and already installed the application with the old key on the device. At this point the old key get's cached on the device and installed the application over the old installation with the new API key will not do you any good because the old key will be used.

So, the first and most important thing to do in those cases is: **Delete completely you old application install from the device.**

If you done that and it didn't help, try to remove the **debug.keystore** file from his computer and compile the project again to generate a new keystore. Then generate a new API key, you can follow this blog post guide I wrote:

[Google Maps API V2 Key](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

Finally, please do go over this guide as well to make sure you committed all the steps in integrating the map in the applciation:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: Sir here is what i did,
1- Deleted the debug.keystore
2- Uninstalled the application
3- Executed the application(to generate a new keystore)
4- Obtained a new API Key
5- Inserted the new API Key
6- Executed
I am sorry but its still not working